# Unable to fetch data from Redis in NestJS application

Tags: node.js, redis, nestjs

I have key stored in redis and I am trying to fetch value in nest application but its showing error in console saying:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token d in JSON at position 0
```

and in postmna its showing response as empty json object like this `{ }` why empty object is showing up  if key is available in redis

Below  is my code:

**phone.dto.ts**

```
import { IsNotEmpty, MinLength } from "class-validator";

export class PhoneNumber 
{
 @IsNotEmpty({message: 'Phone number cannot be empty'})
 @MinLength(10, {message: 'Invalid phone number'}) 
 phoneNumber:string;
}
```

**subscribe.controller.ts**

```
@Post('location')
async getLocation(@Body(ValidationPipe) phoneNumber:PhoneNumber){
    const loc = await this.subscribeService.getLocation(phoneNumber);
    return loc; 
}
```

**subscribe.service.ts**'

```
 async getLocation(phoneNumber:PhoneNumber){
   
    try{

        console.log(phoneNumber.phoneNumber);
        
        const valu = await this.cacheManager.get(phoneNumber.phoneNumber);
      
        if(valu){
            return valu; 
        }
        else{
            return 'No key found';
        }
      }
     catch(err){
        console.log(err); 
        return err;
     }
 }
```

Someone let me know why I am getting this issue.

Answer (score 0):

you can add data as key :

```
async getLocation(phoneNumber:PhoneNumber){   
try{

    console.log(phoneNumber.phoneNumber);
    
    const valu = await this.cacheManager.get(phoneNumber.phoneNumber);
  
    if(valu){
        return {data:valu}; //like this
    }
    else{
        return 'No key found';
    }
  }
 catch(err){
    console.log(err); 
    return err;
 }
}
```

plz vote up ,if it is useful :)